# error: no suitable video mode found. Booting in blind mode

Tags: boot, grub-legacy

I am trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 server using bootable stick (USB) on Dell VEP4600. I am getting

```
error: no suitable video mode found. Booting in blind mode
```

Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Followed this link https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/virtual-edge-platform-4600-16c_install-guide2_en-us.pdf. After entering into Ubuntu Grub, selected the "install Ubuntu server", then I am getting this error.

Thanks,
Chandra.